# Matrix XMPP received "Not Authorized" tag when sending to specific device using FCM

Tags: c#, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently testing the XMPP library to attempt to send to a single device through Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). I followed the tutorial from this [link](https://gitlab.com/matrix-xmpp/samples/blob/380a384688b28344f9f9b5199981bff9d2cc2fc1/csharp/FirebaseClient/Program.cs), it authenticated successfully, but the message sending failed as I got this tag near the end of all the logs:

```
<not-authorized xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams" />
```

What is causing this issue, and how do I resolve it?

UPDATE:

I noticed this will only happen most of the times when I tried to send it to a single device. On other rare times, it successfully sends the message. What is the cause for this random behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the tag above indicated that I was trying to send a message before authentication has completed.

From this [link](https://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3920.html#streams), at **4.7.3 Defined Conditions**

> <not-authorized/> -- the entity has attempted to send data before the
>   stream has been authenticated, or otherwise is not authorized to
>   perform an action related to stream negotiation; the receiving entity
>   MUST NOT process the offending stanza before sending the stream error.

I hope this post will help anyone trying out XMPP protocol. The link provides a lot of information about it.